# Need a sql query for this scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as below. I need result AssetID which does not even complete one task.

```
CREATE TABLE #T(AssetId INT,TaskName varchar(100),StartTime DATE,EndTime date)
go

insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(10,'task1','2016-01-11','2016-04-12')</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(10,'task2','2016-01-11',NULL)
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(10,'task3','2016-01-11','2016-12-11')</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(11,'task4','2016-01-11','2016-04-12')</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(11,'task1','2016-01-11','2016-04-12')</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(11,'task2','2016-01-11',NULL)</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(12,'task1','2016-01-11',null)</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(12,'task2','2016-01-11',null)</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(12,'task3','2016-01-11',null)</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(13,'task1','2016-01-11',null)</b>
insert into #t(AssetId,TaskName,StartTime,EndTime) values(13,'task2','2016-01-11',null)</b>
```

So the result need as below

```
12  task1   11-01-2016  NULL
12  task2   11-01-2016  NULL
12  task3   11-01-2016  NULL
13  task1   11-01-2016  NULL
13  task2   11-01-2016  NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need *assetid* then use `group by`:

```
select assetid
from #t
group by assetid
having count(endtime) = 0;
```

If you want rows, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(endtime) over (partition by assetid) as cntet
      from #t t
     ) t
where cntet = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Gorden's answer is perfectly fine and it may generate better query plan as it only scan the table once.

but just to introduce you with very useful `Exists` clause.It can be done using exists like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM #T AS a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM #T AS b
                   WHERE a.AssetId  = b.AssetId 
                   AND b.EndTime IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if the below query works for this .

```
Select * from #T where assetID not in (Select distinct assetid from #T where endtime is not null )
```

Comment: kirub Please turn this into a more assertive answer or wait until you have the privilege to ask for clarification in comments ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead  ). Also, to make it more readable by formatting read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .